# python regex read raw UDP data into 3d point

Tags: python, regex, parsing, point

Currently I am reading in data from a UDP client that looks like this:

```
X,-3.6958579946845745e+001,Y,-1.6998436983768425e+001,Z,-8.2843220475401704e+000
X,-3.6958578049325865e+001,Y,-1.6998421509164846e+001,Z,-8.2843157671767944e+000
X,-3.6958558150477288e+001,Y,-1.6998528495040631e+001,Z,-8.2843652460239454e+000
```

I have set up a server that reads in the raw data and I then need to parse the data into 3 separate values.

```
import socket

UDP_IP_ADDRESS = ''
UDP_PORT_NO = 5005

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind((UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))

while True:
    data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(4096)
    x,y,z = parse_data(raw_data) #parse into 3 distinct values
```

The part I'm stuck on is actually defining the `parse_data()` function. I am only familiar with simple parsing of comma delimited or space delimited lines. And I tried using [txt2re](https://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=X%2C-3.6958579946845745e%2B001%2CY%2C-1.6998436983768425e%2B001%2CZ%2C-8.2843220475401704e%2B000&submit=Show+Matches) but could not make sense of the regular expresion that I needed to create.

A defined `parse_data()` function that uses `regular expressions` also seems the right fit here because of its ability to provide low latency. A quick one liner would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you need to capture the full number as a single string value (e.g. `-3.6958579946845745e+001`) or do you need to capture the magnitude separately (e.g. `xValue = -3.6958579946845745` and `xMagnitude = 1`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for a one-liner:

```
x, y, z = map(float, raw_data.split(',')[1::2])
```